# Using styled DataGrid but processRowUpdate props cannot be called

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Tech Stack :

- mui-x Data Grid v6.12.1

Context :

- Using styled DataGrid for changing color rows based on classname

Expected Output :

- Prop ProcessRowUpdate triggered

Real Output :

- ProcessRowUpdate not triggered

I declare a styled datagrid with this block :

```
const DataGridBank = styled(DataGrid, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'sx' })(() => ({
    '& .row-idle': {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    '& .row-delete': {
      backgroundColor: '#fc8b72',
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: lighten('#fc8b72', 0.2),
      },
      '&.Mui-selected': {
        backgroundColor: darken('#fc8b72', 0.2),
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: lighten('#fc8b72', 0.2),
        },
      },
    },
  }));
```

And declare the component here :

```
<DataGridBank
        rows={ven_bank}
        columns={columns}
        editMode="row"
        rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
        onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
        onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
        processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
        slots={{
          toolbar: EditToolbar,
        }}
        slotProps={{
          toolbar: { setVen_bank, setRowModesModel, idParent },
        }}
        getRowClassName={(params) => {
          console.log(params);
          if (params.row.method == 'delete') {
            return 'row-delete';
          } else {
            return 'row-idle';
          }
        }}
        autoHeight
/>
```

for the context of the code, the data grid styled apply conditional styling when a row is fetched from db, it is staged to be deleted and then row color turned red.
in the documentation, processRowUpdate will be triggered when edit mode in rows changed from edit to view.
this it the processRowUpdate function :

```
const processRowUpdate = (newRow) => {
    console.log(newRow);
    const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
    let prevData = [];
    ven_bank.map((row) => {
      if (row.id === newRow.id) {
        if (row.isDb === true) {
          prevData.push({ ...updatedRow, method: 'update' });
        } else {
          prevData.push(updatedRow);
        }
      } else {
        prevData.push(row);
      }
    });
    setVen_bank(prevData);
    return updatedRow;
  };
```

i try to to change the component between DataGrid and styled (DataGridBank). Function processrowupdate triggers when using DataGrid. i assume prop not passed when using styled, could you give me insight what else could be happened?

I use DataGrid instead styled DataGrid